# how to redirect a user to his account page after login?

Tags: drupal, redirect, authentication

How to achieve this functionality using drupal?! I have tried triggers and actions and login destination module too.

any ideas?!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this. Just to name a few:

- Triggers & Actions
- [Rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules)
- [LoginToboggan module](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan)

**Tutorials:**

Triggers & Actions: http://drupal.org/node/789066

Rules module: http://drupal.org/node/298506.

- You may also use `user` instead of `user/[account:uid]` (as shown in the tutorial), if you don't have the [Token module](http://drupal.org/project/token) and will still be redirected to your profile.